# OS X Lion installer gives an error trying to run

Tags: macos, install

I just downloaded OS X Lion DMG and am trying to install it.

When i double click on the DMG file a new window popups with setup instructions. After choosing a disc drive target to install on to I get the following message:

```
An error occurred while preparing the installation. Try running this application again.
```

Is the DMG is corrupted or do I need to give any special permission to it to use it to install Lion?

Answer (score 1):

After doing research i found very useful answer and following this answer now, i have installed OS successfully.

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hu2GO9IVUuo